# How do I get started with the M-Project on Windows?

Tags: windows, javascript

This website for this great tool, called [the M-Project](http://www.the-m-project.org/) says that I will need to add a doskey like this:

```
doskey espresso=node C:\Path\To\Espresso\bin\espresso.js $1 $2 $3 $4
```

It is a tool for creating Native mobile apps with the Phonegap/Cordova library, and it seems to be something that would be very helpful in this process.

If I enter that at a command prompt in Windows 7 or 8, it's not going to stick around or persist.  Is it an Environment Variable?

Then it says that it will work with Windows with some additional tools installed.  The next line says that `Node.js` is needed, so I don't know if that is the additional tools mentioned above.

Also, in an old discussion I read that one could just install cygwin.  What would that do?  It doesn't actually install any of the Linux distributions.  I did install Ubuntu 12.04 server with VirtualBox because I thought it would be good to learn more about using Linux as I manage websites that are on a dedicated host.

Anyway, the suggestion to install cygwin did not go into any details... I guess it would allow one to create a bash profile?  Which would only work in a cygwin Command Line Window.  Is that right?  Isn't there a similar file that one could use in Windows or an Environment Variable that one could set to be able to achieve the same result?

Comment: This might help: [How to use Espresso on Windows](http://panacodalabs.github.com/The-M-Docs/#tutorials/how_to_use_espresso_on_windows) – it lists the additional tools.